# 'Index' in namespace 'Eigen' does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt, eigen, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to use pcl library in a Qt project. I included following header files, which give me errors:

```
#include "pcl/common/common_headers.h"
#include "pcl/io/io.h"
```

The errors happens in eigen's header file (LDLT.h, LLT.h):

```
'Index' in namespace 'Eigen' does not name a type
'Solve' in namespace 'Eigen' does not name a type
```

I did see the definition of Index in LDLT.h and LLT.h files. I don't know why giving me these errors.

Comment: What version of Eigen are you using? (`std::cout << EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION << '.' << EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION << '.' << EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION << '\n';`)

Comment: @chtz The version is 3.3

Comment: Eigen 3.3.0 (and later) definitely has these types. Either your installation of Eigen is broken, or something else is broken. Can you provide a MVCE?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not calling them in the right way... I cannot really say without any code, I'll try to guess!
To be clear:

1. `Index` is a typedef declared inside the class LDLT or LLT: you should decide which one you want to use! Please notice that `Index` is declared also inside the class `EigenSolver` and in other classes; again, decide which one you want to use.
2. `solve` is a method of the given class (LDLT, LLT)

You could use two approaches:

```
using namespace Something;
```

where `Something = LDLT` or  `Something = LLT` or

```
Eigen::LDLT<Eigen::MatrixXd>::Index your_stuff_with_index = whatever;
```

Replace `LDLT<Eigen::MatrixXd>` with whatever you have.

Regarding 2., you should call the solve method like the following:

```
LDLT<MatrixXd> chol = whatever;  
.......
.......
result = chol.solve(stuff);
```